# Can I use phonegap in my Java Project?

Tags: java, cordova, nativeapplication, phonegap-4.0.0

I have a big java project for an E-Commerce website, now I want to use PhoneGap to build the cross-platform application. Is there any way to build cross-platform applications?

Comment: Well you will mostly use phonegap for creating client for mobile apps and its actually makes use of html/js. So, can you give more details on what you really need.

Comment: Lets start with an example, I have xyz.com which is a B2B ecommerce website made in Java Platform. Now I want to make its crossplatform apps like in ios or in android or in any other platform, then how can I use phonegap to fulfill these needs. Is it possible to use phonegap plugins in my project?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Eclipse > Help > Eclipse Marketplace and search for [THyM](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article3.php):

> https://github.com/eclipse/thym
>
> Thym (The HYbrid Mobile) project delivers IDE components and a
>   framework for developing Hybrid Mobile Applications on the Eclipse
>   platform. The delivered IDE components support the Apache Cordova
>   framework, but facilitates extensibility to other frameworks.